# Ошибка запуска тестов через make.file make: *** [src/.venv/touchfile] Ошибка 9009

Tags: python, python-3.x, makefile, pytest

Проект https://gitlab.com/nanuchi/gitlab-cicd-crash-course.

В make.file данного проекта есть задача, при которой возникает ошибка

> make: *** [src/.venv/touchfile] Ошибка 9009

```
SRC_DIR := src
test: venv  ##  Unit tests for Flask app
    . $(SRC_DIR)/.venv/bin/activate \
    && pytest -v
```

Версия python:

```
 python --version
```

> Python 3.11.0

```
make --version
```

> GNU Make 3.81 Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc. This
> is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
> warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
> PURPOSE.
>
> This program built for i386-pc-mingw32

В переменные среды вроде всё прописал:

```
echo $Env:PATH
```

> C:\Python311\Scripts;C:\Python311;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
> Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Users*\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program
> Files\nodejs;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program
> Files\Git\cmd;C:\Kotlin\kotlinc_1_8_0\bin;%MAVEN_HOME\bin;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\bin;C:\Program
> Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\Program Files
> (x86)\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Users*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program
> Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
> 2022.2.4\bin;C:\Users*\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users*\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft
> VS Code\bin

Установил пакет pytest:

```
pip install -U pytest
```

> Requirement already satisfied: pytest in
> c:\python311\lib\site-packages (7.4.0) Requirement already satisfied:
> iniconfig in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from pytest) (2.0.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: packaging in
> c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from pytest) (23.1) Requirement
> already satisfied: pluggy<2.0,>=0.12 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages
> (from pytest) (1.3.0) Requirement already satisfied: colorama in
> c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from pytest) (0.4.6)

Но по прежнему получаю ошибку

> python3 -m venv src/.venv Python make: *** [src/.venv/touchfile]
> Ошибка 9009

при запуске команды

```
make test
```

Пробовал выполнять команды:

```
python -m venv src/.venv
python3 -m venv src/.venv
```

, но это результата не дало